# GraphPlot with black edges no rendering function

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks, color

Is there any way to make the edges of a GraphPlot black without tediously writing out a long "EdgeRenderingFunction"? I guess you could ask the same kind of question about vertex labeling.

For example, if I write `EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Black, Arrow[#1, 0.1]} &)` I don't even get the standard directed edges, I get "arrows". How do I just turn the standard directed edges black (instead of the default red)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `Graph` instead of `GraphPlot` you get many convenient options for styling as shown in @ubpdqn's answer.

**If you *have to* use `GraphPlot`**:

You can use the option `PlotStyle->Black` to get black edges.

To style the vertices you can post-process the output  to change `Text` primitives into  graphics primitives of your choice. For example:

```
el={1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 2,  4 -> 4};

g1 = GraphPlot[el, VertexLabeling -> True, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]];
g2 = Block[{j = 1}, g1 /. Text[x_, y_] :> {ColorData[63, "ColorList"][[j++]], 
                           Disk[y, .2], Black, Style[Text[x[[1]], y], 20, Bold]}];

Row[{g1, g2}]
```

[image]

If the input graph does not have vertex labels:

```
el2 = RandomSample[{5 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 4}];

g2a = GraphPlot[el2, ImageSize -> 350, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]];
g2b = Block[{j = 1},  g2a /. Point[x_] :> 
     With[{k = j++}, {ColorData[63, "ColorList"][[k]], Disk[x, .21], 
       Black, Style[ Text[k, x], 20, Bold]}]];

Row[{g2a, g2b}]
```

[image]

However, using edge and vertex rendering functions is not much more tedious than the post-processing approach.

For example, changing `Arrow` to `Line` in your code gives black lines; and the `VertexRenderingFunction` you would need is very similar to the right-hand side of the replacement rule used above.

```
g3 = GraphPlot[el, EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Thick,Black, Line[#1]} &)]
```

[image]

```
g4 = GraphPlot[el, EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Thick, Black, Line[#1]} &),
  VertexRenderingFunction -> ({ColorData[63, "ColorList"][[#2]],
                               Disk[#, .1], Black, Text[#2, #1]} &)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

`Graph` (version 9) is very flexible:

For example:

[image]

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, 
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.02], Black], VertexSize -> 0.2, 
 VertexStyle -> Red]
```